# Merge a list to new column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge a id from a list to a new column in a dataframe, based on other columns values

href id

```
'/soccer/england/premier-league/everton-arsenal/jkor5WO3/',
'/soccer/italy/serie-a/empoli-udinese/YoCoqht3/',
'/soccer/italy/serie-a/cagliari-torino/feDspYQd/',
'/soccer/spain/laliga/getafe-ath-bilbao/8xCPNQo5/',
'/soccer/spain/laliga2/zaragoza-eibar/xW0HLT6q/',
'/soccer/spain/laliga2/cartagena-sad-tenerife/veaBCjUS/',
'/soccer/spain/laliga2/girona-leganes/OSzr7Uij/',
'/soccer/france/ligue-2/niort-toulouse/8MqRAkTq/',
'/soccer/netherlands/eerste-divisie/jong-ajax-fc-emmen/2J3pyvSc/',
'/soccer/netherlands/eerste-divisie/jong-az-alkmaar-excelsior/tA2lzbs4/'
```

So, for example, the second href id has 'empoli' and 'udinese' in the url. The href id should be in the row where columns has 'empoli' and 'udinese' or similar values.

dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'HomeTeam':['Empoli','Getafe','Cagliari','Everton'],'AwayTeam':['Udinese','Athletic Bilbao','Torino','Arsenal']})
```

Expected Output

```
   HomeTeam         AwayTeam                                                 ID
0    Empoli          Udinese     /soccer/italy/serie-a/empoli-udinese/YoCoqht3/
1    Getafe  Athletic Bilbao   /soccer/spain/laliga/getafe-ath-bilbao/8xCPNQo5/
2  Cagliari           Torino    /soccer/italy/serie-a/cagliari-torino/feDspYQd/
3   Everton          Arsenal  /soccer/england/premier-league/everton-arsenal...
```

Comment: Please also post the expected output.

Comment: How do you know what the team names are in the case of "jong-az-alkmaar-excelsior" or "cartagena-sad-tenerife", where there is more than one "-"?

Comment: @RichardKYu maybe we could implement the fuzzywuzzy module?

Comment: Possibly. But do you have a list somewhere of all soccer team names that are active? I think I could make do with that too

Comment: yes, from the HomeTeam and AwayTeam I can make a list with unique values

Comment: Is a solution where we generate a new table entirely based on splitting the team names in the ID, instead of matching and then adding the ID column, acceptable?

Comment: it sounds good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I have used an implementation involving fuzzywuzzy to make the matches, then afterward I inserted the new column into an existing DataFrame.

**Edit:** to add in scraping code provided by poster. Also, hardcoded in another team name to show that the proper link matches.

**Edit2:** changed default scorer parameter in extractOne to be partial ratio instead.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def monthToNum(month):
    return {
            'January': 1,
            'February': 2,
            'March': 3,
            'April': 4,
            'May': 5,
            'June': 6,
            'July': 7,
            'August': 8,
            'September': 9, 
            'October': 10,
            'November': 11,
            'December': 12
    }[month]

dates_unique = ['Monday 6 December 2021']
href_ids=list()
for a in dates_unique:
    try:
      r = requests.get(f'https://www.betexplorer.com/results/soccer/?year={a.split(" ")[3]}&month={monthToNum(a.split(" ")[2])}&day={a.split(" ")[1]}')
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
      r = requests.get(f'https://www.betexplorer.com/results/soccer/?year={a.split(" ")[3]}&month={monthToNum(a.split(" ")[2])}&day={a.split(" ")[1]}')
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    f = soup.find_all('td', class_="table-main__tt")
    for h in f:
      href_ids.append(h.find('a')['href'])

infos = href_ids


df= pd.DataFrame({'HomeTeam':['Empoli','Getafe','Cagliari','Everton', 'Buxton'],'AwayTeam':['Udinese','Athletic Bilbao','Torino','Arsenal', 'Scarborough']})

dict_ids ={}


for info in infos:
    team_name_pieces = " ".join(info.split("/")[4].split("-"))
    
    dict_ids[info] = team_name_pieces

id_results_column = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    result = process.extractOne(row[1][0] + " " +row[1][1], dict_ids.keys(),scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio)
    id_results_column.append(result[0])


df['ID'] = id_results_column

print(df)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: yes I need it into the original dataframe because I have other columns and 'ID' should merge in that exact row in the original dataframe

Comment: @luka Have used fuzzywuzzy to make the matching and extraction after storing the URL-derived information in a dictionary. Let me know if this works now for you! You can print(result) in the for loop to see the similarity score given by fuzzywuzzy when making the match.

Comment: why my output is different for the second row?

Comment: @luka Are you using exact initial df as me or different one? You may have more rows/columns in your row and therefore the matching might be different, I don't have the full data table you have so I can only work with the 4 rows given. Also, can you show me the result you are getting?

Comment: yes but I have more IDs in my list

Comment: @luka If I have full list of IDs (or how you are grabbing them) I may be able to help you with the problem. Otherwise, it will be difficult for me to understand the problem you are having without such information. It might be easier to ask a new question given how the scope of your problem is changing now to include more information.

Comment: I added how I scrape ids

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240933/discussion-between-richard-k-yu-and-luka).